# Clipping image/remove background programmatically in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, conv-neural-network

How to go from the image on the left to the image on the right programmatically using Python (and maybe some tools, like OpenCV)?

[image: original]
[image: processed]

I made this one by hand using an online tool for clipping. I am completely noob in image processing (especially in practice). I was thinking to apply some edge or contour detection to create a mask, which I will apply later on the original image to paint everything else (except the region of interest) black. But I failed miserably.

The goal is to preprocess a dataset of very similar images, in order to train a CNN binary classifier. I tried to train it by just cropping the image close to the region of interest, but the noise is so high that the CNN learned absolutely nothing.

Can someone help me do this preprocessing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used OpenCV's implementation of [watershed](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga3267243e4d3f95165d55a618c65ac6e1) algorithm to solve your problem. You can find out how to use it if you read [this great tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html), so I will not explain this into a lot of detail.

I selected four points (markers). One is located on the region that you want to extract, one is outside and the other two are within lower/upper part of the interior that does not interest you. I then created an empty integer array (the so-called marker image) and filled it with zeros. Then I assigned unique values to pixels at marker positions.

The image below shows the marker positions and marker values, drawn on the original image:

[image]

I could also select more markers within the same area (for example several markers that belong to the area you want to extract) but in that case they should all have the same values (in this case 255).

Then I used watershed. The first input is the image that you provided and the second input is the marker image (zero everywhere except at marker positions). The algorithm stores the result in the marker image; the region that interests you is marked with the value of the region marker (in this case 255):

[image]

I set all pixels that did not have the 255 value to zero. I dilated the obtained image three times with 3x3 kernel. Then I used the dilated image as a mask for the original image (i set all pixels outside the mask to zero) and this is the result i got:

[image]

You will probably need some kind of method that will find markers automatically. The difficulty of this task depends heavily on the set of the input images. In some cases, the method can be really straightforward and simple (as in the tutorial linked above) but sometimes this can be a tough nut to crack. But I can't recommend anything because I don't know how your images look like in general (you only provided one). :)

Comment: Seems very promising. All the images are very similar, so I could make a mask out of the mean or/and standard dev of the whole dataset. I will try to make it today or tomorrow and I'll let you know how it went. Good job, thanks!